# I need some commands for minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Ok so I need some commands for minecraft pc. The commands I need specifically are;
The command to keep my inventory after death. 
Summoning giants, & undead horses
Teleporting to spawn(if that is possible)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Asking four different questions in one is a bad idea.

Comment: ... and makes the question "too broad" (the close reason explicitly states "Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"The command to keep my inventory after death":*

```
/gamerule keepInventory true
```

*"Summoning giants":*

```
/summon Giant
```

*"undead horses":*

```
/summon EntityHorse ~ ~ ~ {Type:3}
```

*"Teleporting to spawn(if that is possible)":*

Not easily possible unless you have the coordinates of spawn, or keep a certain marker entity at spawn.

---

[This wiki page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands), or a command tutorial, is a better place to search up commands and their syntax.

Comment: Would a beacon work

Comment: @AndrewEckert Nope.

Comment: @Andrew Eckert you need an entity(Mob/Item/etc.) at your spawnpoint or its coordinates